# What is happening with inheritance in my example? And, what is the proper terminology in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

I am learning OOP and have a question about what is exactly happening with the code below.

I have the classic `Dog` `Animal` example going. `Dog` inherits `Animal`.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Speak()
    {
        return "Animal Speak";
    }

    public string Hungry()
    {
        return this.Speak();
    }
}


public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override string Speak()
    {
        return "Dog Speak";
    }

    public string Fetch()
    {
        return "Fetch";
    }
}
```

Both questions are based on this assignment: `Animal a = new Dog();`

1. What is actually happening when I declare an `Animal` and set it to a `Dog` reference. Is there a specific term for this?
2. When I call `a.Hungry()`, the output is "Dog Speak." If the output is "Dog Speak", why can I not call `a.Fetch()`? What is the term for what's happening here?

Any help and further reading on the particular topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. This is an "upcast".  In C# there is an implicit conversion from any type to any of it's base types, so you don't need to do anything to treat a `Dog` as if it were an `Animal`.  (Thanks to Matt Burland for reminding me that this is the appropriate term.)
2. Because the type of the variable is `Animal`, and as such you can only access members that the compiler *knows* an `Animal` can access, i.e. `Speak` and `Hungry`.  It doesn't know that the `Animal` is a `Dog`, so it can't call `Fetch`.  The variable would need to be of type `Dog` for you to be able to call `Fetch` on it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

Is upcasting. You are creating a `Dog` object and assigning it to a variable of the parent class. This is allowed, but...

```
a.Fetch();
```

Won't work. Why, because `Animal` doesn't have a method called `Fetch`, and as far as the compiler knows, `a` can be any `Animal`. If you want to call `Fetch` you will need to cast `a` back to a `Dog`

```
Dog d = (Dog)a;
d.Fetch();
```

Note however, that this will cause an error if `a` isn't a `Dog`, so usually you check first:

```
if (a is Dog) 
{
    Dog d = (Dog)a;
    d.Fetch();
}
```

When you call

```
a.Hungry();
```

This is allowed, because `Animal` has a `Hungry` method. The `Hungry` method called `Speak`, but since `a` is a `Dog` and not the base `Animal`, it'll call the `Dog.Speak` method (this, as Servy pointed out elsewhere, is true polymorphism - the idea the actual code executed when calling a particular method will be different depending on the actual type of the object).

Comment: +1 for being the only person (myself included) to answer #1 correctly.  Going to edit my answer now.

Comment: Great informative answer. In addition, if you wanted to have a common `Fetch()` functionality, you could create an interfaced named `IFetchable` which contains the `Fetch()` method. Then `Dog` would implement it and then you could access it that way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your are storing an object of type `Dog` inside an variable that will accept any `Animal`.  This is called [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) *(actually not quite see Servy's comment)*
2. You can only call fetch by first casting the object to a dog

Like so:

```
Dog dog = (Dog)a;
dog.Fetch();
```

Otherwise as far as the compiler knows it could be any animal, and not all animals have the method `Fetch`.  Also note the cast would throw an `InvalidCastError` if it was not actually a `Dog` object.

Comment: To #1, it's not *exactly* polymorphism.  Polymorphism is the idea that calling a method of `a` may not be implemented in the definition of the type `Animal`, it can be (and in this case, is) executing a method defined in a derived type.  Therefore the ability to sore a `Dog` in an `Animal` isn't polymorphism, the fact that the result of `Speak` is `"Dog Speak"`, is polymorphism.  If the method was not virtual, it would not be polymorphic, and would thus say `"Animal Speak"`, but you can still put a `Dog` into an `Animal` variable without polymorphism.

Comment: Interesting I actually thought that was the correct use of the term Polymorphism, thanks for the info.  Learn something new every day!

Comment: This is actually relevant in C# where you can have non-polymorphic behavior (by not adding virtual).  In, for example, Java, you can't have a non-virtual method, so it's not really relevant to make the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

1. `a` is an `Animal` reference and it points to a `Dog` object. This is a form of polymorphism (subtype polymorphism).
2. You can't call `a.Fetch` since `a` has type `Animal` and the `Fetch` method is not defined in your `Animal` class.

Comment: #1 isn't "polymorphism" as per [this comment of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406337/what-is-happening-with-inheritance-in-my-example-and-what-is-the-proper-termin/14406398#comment20046699_14406398).  If the method wasn't virtual you could still have an upcast (which is the correct answer to #1) even though it would have no polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 1):

the word for that is **polymorphism**

1. because your animal just happened to be instantiated as a `Dog`, and it will execute all of `Dog`'s methods.  Both `Animal` and `Dog` have a `Speak` method, and `Dog` inherits `Hungry` from `Animal`.`Dog`'s `speak` method overrides `Animal's`, so that's what gets executed.
2. the reason why you can't write `a.Fetch` is because the compiler doesn't know that at design time.

for example

```
Animal a;

if(console.ReadLine() == "Dog")
{
    a = new Dog();
}
else
{
    a = new Animal();
}

a.Fetch();
```

at this point when you call `a.Fetch` you don't know whether or not a is a dog

Comment: #1 isn't strictly polymorphism.  See my comment on KD's answer, or Matt Burland's answer, which is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you Create an Animal with a Dog, you only create  A Animal and Have only the Propertys of Animal. This has an Simply Reason. Just a Example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Speak()
    {
        return "Animal Speak";
    }

    public string Hungry()
    {
        return this.Speak();
    }
}


public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override string Speak()
    {
        return "Dog Speak";
    }

    public string Fetch()
    {
        return "Fetch";
    }
}

public class Cat: Animal
{
    public override string Speak()
    {
        return "Cat Speak";
    }

    public string Fetch()
    {
        return "Fetch";
    }
}
```

So if you now Crate a Insance like this:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

You know that your Animal can Speak and that he is Hungry, Nothing more thats all that you need to know, you can Call `a.Speak()` and your Animal returns `"Dog Speak"` buf if you now change a like this: `a = new Cat()` you can call `a.Speak()` too but it Return something else ... the same call but different returns. Of course if you are sure that the Animal is really a Dog you can cast it back to the Explicit implementation.

```
var d= new Dog();
if(a is Dog)
d = a as Dog;
```

d is now a real Dog and can everything that only a Dog can but you cant assign anymore d as a Cat. Becorse its a Dog and not an Animal

[Why as and not Cast?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. when you declare an `Animal` and set it to a `dog` implicit cast is done
2. try this code to see the effect of using `virtual` and not using it.

:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Speak()
    {
        return "Animal Speak";
    }
    public string Hungry()
    {
        return this.Speak();
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public new string Speak()
    {
        return "Dog Speak";
    }
    public string Fetch()
    {
        return "Fetch";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Animal a = new Dog();
    Console.WriteLine(a.Hungry());   //Animal Speak
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Your #2 is just a further explanation of #1.  You don't answer his question marked #2.

Comment: in #1 I tried to answer his #1 sentence. in #2 I want to say when it is possible to reach the `Speak` Method in the base class.

Comment: As I said before, you don't answer his second question, which he has marked as #2, in which he asks why `a.Fetch` is not legal.

Comment: in #2 he is surprised why the `speak` method returns that value! so it seems it has two question in #2. I answered one of them. you also didn't say (in your answer) why the `speak` method returns "Dog Speak"!

Comment: No, he wasn't saying he was surprised that it returned that value.  He was asking why `a.Fetch` isn't valid *given the behavior of* `a.Hungry`, not asking why `a.Hungry` returns `"Dog Speak"` instead of `"Animal Speak"`.

Comment: anyway I think my answer mentioned something useful (even if I misunderstand the question or not) and he got the idea.

Comment: You answered the first question fairly well.  You have not answered the second question at all, as my first comment states.